# Show that any finite purely inseparable extensions has a $p-$basis.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

A set $\{a_1,...,a_n\} \subseteq K$ is said to be a $p-$basis for $K/F$ provided that there is a chain of proper extensions

$F \subset F(a_1) \subset \cdots \subset F(a_n)=K$.

Show that any finite purely inseparable extensions has a $p-$basis.

Now my intution is I can treat the purely inseparable extension as a simple extension then I am done. But Is this intution true then how to prove this?
If not then how should I approach to this problem?

Comment: I don't think every purely inseparable extension is simple, e.g., $F$ is the rational functions in variables $u$ and $v$ over the field of $p$ elements, and $K$ is the extension by the $p$-th roots of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: then how should I approach to this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you have stated the question correctly? $F(a_n)=K$ can't happen, for the $F$ and $K$ in the example I gave.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that if the intution is not true then how should I approach? If you think the question is wrong then give counter example where a finite purely inseparable extensions does not have a p−basis.

Comment: If $F$ and $K$ are the fields I mentioned in my first comment, then there is no $a_n$ in $K$ such that $F(a_n)=K$. I think you have the wrong definition of $p$-basis. See page 183 of http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1940-46-02/S0002-9904-1940-07169-1/S0002-9904-1940-07169-1.pdf (the rest of the article might interest you, as well). See also http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=48662

Comment: You might try page 463 of Kung, A Source Book in Matroid Theory. That page seems to be available at Google Books.

Comment: Without saying that $K$ is a simple extension of $F$, is there any process to process that $K$ has a $p$-basis?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by a $p$-basis. What you have written as the definition implies that $K$ is a simple extension of $F$ – that's what $K=F(a_n)$ means – so if you insist on that definition then no, there is no way to get to $K$ having a $p$-basis without saying $K$ is a simple extension of $F$. So I really, really think you have been given the wrong definition for $p$-basis, and that's why you are having so much trouble. Have you looked at the sources I mentioned?

Comment: In Patrick Morandi's book "field and galois theory" the definition is given just see p.no: 50.

Comment: I don't think the example you have given is finite extension. Anyway ....

Comment: The extension I gave has degree $p^2$. It's finite. I did find the definition in the book you mention. It's wrong. It's wrong. It's wrong. It's wrong. It's wrong. Just because it got published in a book, that doesn't mean it's right. Books have mistakes. It's wrong. It's wrong. It's wrong. It's wrong. It's wrong.

Comment: Okay. You are right. It is in the book, does not mean the definition should be valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that if $\{a_1, ... ,a_n\}$ is a $p$-basis for $K/F$, then $[K: F] = p^n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513249/show-that-if-a-1-a-n-is-a-p-basis-for-k-f-then-k-f-pn)

Comment: This is a known error in the book. The inclusions should read $F \subset F(a_1) \subset \dots \subset F(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}) \subset F(a_1,\dots,a_n) = K$. See https://web.nmsu.edu/~pamorand/Errata.pdf

Answer (score 1):

*Incorporating the comments above by @GerryMyerson.*

---

The question as stated is incorrect without additional hypotheses on the extension $K/F$. For, let $k = \mathbb{F}_p$, and define $F = k(x^p,y^p)$ and $K = k(x,y)$. Then, $K/F$ is a finite purely inseparable extension (in fact $[K:F] = p^2$) which is not simple. So, there is no $p$-basis for $K$ as per the definition given in the question details.

However, this is a known error in the textbook. The inclusions should read $$F \subset F(a_1) \subset F(a_1,a_2) \subset \dots \subset F(a_1,\dots,a_n) = K.$$ See [here](https://web.nmsu.edu/~pamorand/Errata.pdf) for a list of errata.

[This paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1940-46-02/S0002-9904-1940-07169-1/S0002-9904-1940-07169-1.pdf) might also be a useful resource to look at (in particular, see page 183). You might also try page 463 of Kung's *A Source Book in Matroid Theory* (this page seems to be available on Google Books).

The corrected version of this question is asked and answered here: [Show that if $\{a_1, ... ,a_n\}$ is a $p$-basis for $K/F$, then $[K: F] = p^n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2513249/279515)